# How to add to rows with certain not null column row with this column being null?

Tags: sql, db2

I've only started learning SQL, I need your help.

I have an sql data that looks like this:

| Type | Group |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | A |
| Orange |  |
| Kiwi | B |
| Apple |  |
| Orange |  |
| Kiwi | C |
| Apple | C |
| Apple | C |

What I need to achive is data that will group the raw one by type and group and also have a column, in which will be stored the amount of fruits. The problem is that it is necessary to add amount of fruits to rows with the same type from rows, that does not have column group filled.

Basically the result set should look like this:

| Type | Group | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | A | 2 |
| Apple | C | 3 |
| Apple |  | 1 |
| Kiwi | B | 1 |
| Kiwi | C | 1 |
| Orange |  | 2 |

What I achive is only the following SQL query, which does not cover the task properly.

```
SELECT type, group, count (fruitid) as amount
FROM table
GROUP BY type, group
```

Comment: Based on your example table and expected result, is it `Type = Apple` and `Group = A` should be 1 while `Type = Apple` and `Group = C` should be 2 and so on? Maybe I'm wrong but just trying to figure out what you expected...

Comment: `Group` and `Table` aren't good names to use in an example query because they're not only reserved words in every SQL DBMS but they're also essential keywords in SQL. How about something like `GrpCode` and `Items` instead? Similarly, `Type` may not be a SQL reserved word but it also could be adjusted to something clearer like `ItemType`

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
WITH 
  TAB (Type, Group) AS
(
  VALUES
  ('Apple', 'A')
, ('Orange', NULL)  
, ('Kiwi',  'B')
, ('Apple', NULL)
, ('Orange',    NULL)
, ('Kiwi',  'C')
, ('Apple', 'C')
, ('Apple', 'C')
)
, G AS
(
  SELECT 
    TYPE, GROUP
  , COUNT (*) AMOUNT
  FROM TAB
  GROUP BY TYPE, GROUP
)
SELECT 
  A.TYPE, A.GROUP
, A.AMOUNT + COALESCE (B.AMOUNT, 0)
  AS AMOUNT
FROM G A
LEFT JOIN G B
  ON B.TYPE = A.TYPE
     AND A.GROUP IS NOT NULL
     AND B.GROUP IS NULL
ORDER BY A.TYPE, A.GROUP
```

| TYPE | GROUP | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | A | 2 |
| Apple | C | 3 |
| Apple | *null* | 1 |
| Kiwi | B | 1 |
| Kiwi | C | 1 |
| Orange | *null* | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FbqLB78F)

Comment: Mark's use of a common table expression (CTE) to calculate the totals for each Group and Type as a separate step before performing the left join is the right move here, because if the query didn't use a CTE and used a single `SELECT` for the aggregation and the left join, it would cause a Cartesian product for any item that multiple rows in a group and multiple rows in the null group. For example, if item Pear had 3 rows in Group D and two rows with a null group, the correct total for Pear in Group D would be 5, but due to the unwanted Cartesian product, it could return 6: (3*2) or 8: (3*2)+2